# Wampserver using JAVA connexion client-apache-mysql

Tags: java, mysql, apache, server, client

As part of a client-server application, I use WampServer such tool (containing Apach + mysql).
I program my client in JAVA, I would like to lauch SQL queries in MySQL BDDs from the client program, will I go directly from the client to the MySQL server, or have to make the following diagram: Client -> Apach -> MySQL ( where the connexion Apach -> MySQL would be in localhost), and if so how to set Apach to do such things.
Another time I had scheduled a client-server application with Java, but I programmed my own server program, for example he receives ( "Query1") from a client, and this will do an insert into a BDD Firebird.
What I want to know is , is there a possibility to do the same but instead of creating a server-program of mine, i woudl rather use Apach, sending like "QUERY 1" from the client program in Apach and he will know himself he must connect to MySQL on localhost to start SQL insert query in a BDD MySQL?
If this is not possible or not advisable, tell me why Apach is available in wampserver, and what's the best methods to use for a client-server mechanism in java ..
thank you in advance